# Opposite values in R

Tags: r, pca

I try to make PCA for Car93 data, using code from http://florence.acadiau.ca/collab/hugh_public/images/f/f3/Pca.pdf but I receive very strange results, for example, I receive

```
round(loadings(cars.pca)[,1], 3)
     Min.Price              Price          Max.Price           MPG.city 
        -0.005             -0.005             -0.005              0.005 
   MPG.highway         EngineSize         Horsepower                RPM 
         0.005             -0.001             -0.033              0.564 
  Rev.per.mile Fuel.tank.capacity         Passengers             Length 
         0.528             -0.003             -0.001             -0.014 
     Wheelbase              Width        Turn.circle             Weight 
        -0.007             -0.004             -0.003             -0.634
```

But I should receive

```
 Min.Price              Price          Max.Price           MPG.city 
            0.005             0.005             0.005              -0.005 
       MPG.highway         EngineSize         Horsepower                RPM 
             -0.005             0.001             0.033              -0.564 
      Rev.per.mile Fuel.tank.capacity         Passengers             Length 
             -0.528             0.003             0.001             0.014 
         Wheelbase              Width        Turn.circle             Weight 
            0.007             0.004             0.003             0.634
```

I can't understand why that's happens...
Also I get unbelieveable summary:

```
    > summary(cars.pca)
Importance of components:
                            Comp.1      Comp.2       Comp.3       Comp.4
Standard deviation     809.7715704 462.9240342 269.70957406 2.726051e+01
Proportion of Variance   0.6948358   0.2270788   0.07708145 7.874538e-04
Cumulative Proportion    0.6948358   0.9219146   0.99899602 9.997835e-01
                             Comp.5       Comp.6       Comp.7       Comp.8
Standard deviation     9.8543848085 8.3562565211 4.076212e+00 2.657464e+00
Proportion of Variance 0.0001029002 0.0000739913 1.760641e-05 7.483277e-06
Cumulative Proportion  0.9998863744 0.9999603657 9.999780e-01 9.999855e-01
                             Comp.9      Comp.10      Comp.11      Comp.12
Standard deviation     2.463855e+00 1.686161e+00 1.455246e+00 1.131083e+00
Proportion of Variance 6.432611e-06 3.012694e-06 2.244038e-06 1.355645e-06
Cumulative Proportion  9.999919e-01 9.999949e-01 9.999971e-01 9.999985e-01
                            Comp.13      Comp.14      Comp.15      Comp.16
Standard deviation     1.026482e+00 5.249720e-01 2.923534e-01 2.182833e-02
Proportion of Variance 1.116502e-06 2.920313e-07 9.056773e-08 5.048914e-10
Cumulative Proportion  9.999996e-01 9.999999e-01 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
```

Can someone explain why it could be? Can it be, that my **R** remembers other data and in some way uses them? (Month ago I used `data<-read.table('C:/Users/Desktop/HPdati/libratable.txt', sep=',', header=TRUE))` in my another code, may it affect my code now? 
My code is:

```
    library(MASS)

#data(Cars93)
head(Cars93)
keep<-rep(F,ncol(Cars93))
for(i in 1:ncol(Cars93)){
keep[i]<-is.numeric(Cars93[,i])
if (any(is.na(Cars93[,i])))keep[i]<-F
}
cars<-Cars93[,keep]
head(Cars93)
#library(mva)
cars.pca<-princomp(cars)
summary(cars.pca)
round(loadings(cars.pca)[,1],3)
sqrt(apply(cars,2,var))


cars.pca<-princomp(cars,cor=T)
summary(cars.pca)
loadings(cars.pca)[,c(1:2,16)]

cars.projected.data<-predict(cars.pca,newdata=cars)
eqscplot(cars.projected.data[,1:2])
identify(cars.projected.data[,1],cars.projected.data[,2],cars93$Make)
```

Comment: I am using "F" as False

Comment: The code you link to claims that `princomp` is in the package **mva**, which does not appear to exist on CRAN. There is a `princomp` function in the stats library that comes with all R distributions. In the documentation for that function, it explicitly notes that "signs of the columns of the loadings and scores are arbitrary, and so may differ between different programs for PCA, and even between different builds of R".

Comment: but how can I know which signs are correct?

Comment: "signs of the columns of the loadings and scores are arbitrary". Arbitrary. They are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

The package `mva` existed many years ago but now all of its functionality is included in package `stats` so the text you're referring to is a bit old. In addition, the part ...

```
keep <- rep(F, ncol(Cars93))
for(i in 1:ncol(Cars93)){
    keep[i] <- is.numeric(Cars93[,i])
    if(any(is.na(Cars93[,i]))) keep[i] <- F
    }
```

... is very un-R-ish, most people would do instead something like ....

```
keep2 <- sapply(Cars93, function(COL) is.numeric(COL) & !any(is.na(COL)))
# isTRUE(all(keep == keep2)) # yes
```

But to the point. The sign of principal components (as noted in comments) is arbitrary so there is nothing strange in your results. In fact, I got the result with opposite sign with `prcomp`, but the same as yours with `princomp` (both functions do PCA but the first uses eigendecomposition whereas the other uses singular values).

Your `summary(cars.pca)` is not unbelievable either. It gives you the variances of PCs based on covariation matrix, whereas `summary(cars.pca, cor=TRUE)` will give you the exactly same results as in the referred text.

And of course you may use F for FALSE and T for TRUE but it is safer to use TRUE and FALSE. What if a random hacker walks to your computer and types:

```
T <- FALSE
F <- TRUE
```

Suddenly, all code based on T==TRUE and F==FALSE is broken. :) You cannot redefine TRUE and FALSE this way.

#### addition

Q: "Can it be, that my R remembers other data and in some way uses them? (Month ago I used data<-read.table('C:/Users/Desktop/HPdati/libratable.txt', sep=',', header=TRUE)) in my another code, may it affect my code now?"

A: "No!"